# bootstrapValidator disable error message

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, message, validation

Is it possible to disable error messages in bootstrapValidator? I have searched in bootstrapValidator settings but there is not such an option. I want to have my custom messages appear and hide based on bootstrapValidator's classes. How can I disable default error-messages from being shown.?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this, as you can already specify your custom messages in bootstrapValidator using the `fields` option. Here is the example of setting custom messages for `fullName` and `email` fields:

```
 fields: {
     fullName: {
         validators: {
             notEmpty: {
                 message: 'The full name is required and cannot be empty'
             }
         }
     },
     email: {
         validators: {
             notEmpty: {
                 message: 'The email address is required and cannot be empty'
             },
             emailAddress: {
                 message: 'The email address is not valid'
             }
         }
     },
```

If you really want to hide all messages, you can use the `container` option:

```
 container: '#messages',
```

and then you can hide that container in your HTML:

```
 <div id="messages" class="hide"></div>
```

Comment: What if you want to hide only one specific message? i've been trying to remove and add fields to the validator but im having troubles to show the message again after removing the field.